# How to populate dropdownbox in SimpleForm

Tags: jquery, sapui5

I'm working on a page that displays a **SimpleForm** element. One of the elements within this SimpleForm is a Dropdownbox. I need to populate this Dropdownbox with values at the time of programming but I seem to be unable to master this using the following code (excerpt):

```
var html =  '<template>' +
        '<div data-sap-ui-type="sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleForm" id="sf2">' +
        '<div data-sap-ui-type="sap.ui.core.Title" id="T1" 
           data-text="Template Text"></div>' +
        '<div data-sap-ui-type="sap.ui.commons.TextArea" id="L1" 
         data-height="500px" data-value="some long text here "></div>' +
        '<div data-sap-ui-type="sap.ui.core.Title" id="T2" 
           data-text="Configuration"></div>' +
        '<div data-sap-ui-type="sap.ui.commons.DropdownBox" id="L3"></div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</template>';

var myView   =  sap.ui.view({id:"myView",viewContent:html,
                            type:sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.HTML})  
                 myView.placeAt("content");
```

I've tried making

```
'<div data-sap-ui-type="sap.ui.commons.DropdownBox" id="L3"></div>' +
```

look like

```
'<div data-sap-ui-type="sap.ui.commons.DropdownBox" id="L3" 
     data-items="/test"></div>' +
```

but encounter the following error when I do that: 
**Uncaught Error: Aggregation items with cardinality 0..n only allows binding paths as attribute value**

I've also tried to define a model like so:

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
oModel.setData({
    hardware:[
        {device:"PC", enabled:true},
        {device:"Monitor", enabled:true},
        {device:"Keyboard", enabled:false},
        {device:"Mouse", enabled:true},
        {device:"Speaker", enabled:false},
        {device:"Printer", enabled:true}],
    editable: true, 
    tooltip: "Device"});
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel);
```

and then populate my field like so:

```
$("#L3").setModel(oModel);
```

but receive the following error when I do that:
**Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function**

I reckon that the line setting the model gets called before #L3 actually exists.

Any idea how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add curly braces to correct binding path for data binding declaration:`data-items="{/hardware}"`

```html
<div data-sap-ui-type="sap.ui.commons.DropdownBox" id="L3" 
 data-items="{/hardware}"></div>
```

2. Add a list item template to Dropdownbox

```html
<div data-sap-ui-type="sap.ui.core.ListItem" data-text="{device}" 
data-enabled="{enabled}" ></div>
```

Please run and check the code snippet. It should answer your question.

One thing which is not relevant to your question is that it is recommended to use [XML view](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/91f292806f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html) or [JS view](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/91f262ef6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html) instead of HTML view which is obsolete.

```html
<script src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" id="sap-ui-bootstrap" data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal" data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m,sap.ui.commons"></script>
  
<script>
  
  var html =  '<template>' +
        '<div data-sap-ui-type="sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleForm" id="sf2">' +
        '<div data-sap-ui-type="sap.ui.core.Title" id="T1" data-text="Template Text"></div>' +
        '<div data-sap-ui-type="sap.ui.commons.TextArea" id="L1" data-height="500px" data-value="some long text here "></div>' +
        '<div data-sap-ui-type="sap.ui.core.Title" id="T2" data-text="Configuration"></div>' +
      '<div data-sap-ui-type="sap.ui.commons.DropdownBox" id="L3" data-items="{/hardware}">'+
      '<div data-sap-ui-type="sap.ui.core.ListItem" data-text="{device}" data-enabled="{enabled}" ></div>'
         
  
        +'</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</template>';

var myView   =  sap.ui.view({id:"myView",viewContent:html,
                            type:sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.HTML}) ; 
                 myView.placeAt("content");
  
  var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
oModel.setData({
    hardware:[
        {device:"PC", enabled:true},
        {device:"Monitor", enabled:true},
        {device:"Keyboard", enabled:false},
        {device:"Mouse", enabled:true},
        {device:"Speaker", enabled:false},
        {device:"Printer", enabled:true}],
    editable: true, 
    tooltip: "Device"});
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel);
  
</script>
         
<body id="content">

</body>
```